# grid.right of dgrid gives error in IE

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I am using dgrid and CellSelection plugin to select a Cell. Suppose grid is of 4 columns, when first Cell is filled with data(by some action, say clicking on button), focus moves to next Cell, again data is filled in this cell , moves focus to next cell and so on.

Above scenario is working fine in **Chrome** and **FF** but it is failing in **IE 9**, it gives this error

**Unable to get value of the property 'className': object is null or undefined**

I am retrieving 'selected cell' like this.

```
grid.on(".dgrid-cell:click", function(evt){
        selectedCell = grid.cell(evt);
```

and here data is filled(by clicking on button) in selectedCell and moves to next cell

```
 var item = grid.store.get(selectedCell.row.data.id);
 item.field = 'FirstCell';
 grid.store.put(item, {
     overwrite : true
 });

 grid.deselect(selectedCell);
 grid.select(grid.right(selectedCell));
```

I found error is thrown in grid.right call but couldn't explore much in it

any suggestions on this?